# google charts RTL support

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Charts in my project, which is a multi-lingual one and hence need to support LTR as well as RTL for the contents.

All looks good except for the included charts where:

- The vertical axis should be displayed at the right,
- All texts (title, legend, etc.) should be shown correctly as if using `dir="auto"`.

Does anyone know how and where this can be configured?

Comment: do you need to load a [specific locale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)? some charts have specific [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#configuration-options) -- the table chart has `rtlTable: boolean`

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat for your response. About **locale**, I don't think so. The site is aimed to support all languages, which are not necessarily mapped to locales in a one-to-one relation. The only thing I need is to correctly display text in RTL languages (for instance, a question in any such language would show the `?` sign at the left and not at the right). You can try Google translate to see what I mean (enter a question in English, and translate it to Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc.; not only the text is aligned to the right, but also punctuation and numbers are specially handled).

Comment: i'm thinking you will need to load a specific locale to achieve

Comment: Hummm... This is really, **really** a bad solution. I'll wait to see if they issue a version that display the same level of support as the hosting browsers. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: if your project includes any server side code, get the locale from the  `Accept-Language` http header and pass it to the page for google charts to load...

Comment: I think it is more complex that that. See? The project is to support a number of INTERFACE languages, whereas the **data** could be in any language, including those that are not included in the list of interface languages. If I could read your mind, I would say "YES, A MESS!!!!".

Comment: got it, finally. sounds like you would have to manually associate locale with the data, somehow...